# Parse unnamed JSON to Swift Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have an unnamed JSON data that looks like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "job_title" : "job_title",
      "fname" : "fname",
      "department" : "department",
      "email" : "",
      "business_phone" : "business_phone",
      "project" : null,
      "location_id" : null,
      "bio" : null,
      "manager_id" : null,
      "team_lead_id" : null,
      "lname" : "lname",
      "project_id" : null,
      "title" : null,
      "user_id" : 1,
      "user_pass" : null,
      "user_name" : "fname-lname",
      "company" : "company",
      "office_location_id" : "office_location"
},
{//Next employee record
//Data
}
]
]
```

And am trying to use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to parse the data into a dictionary that i'll be able to use in other parts of the application.

Here is what i've tried:

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON{
        response in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")  // original URL request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // HTTP URL response
        print("Data: \(String(describing: response.data))")     // server data
        //print("Result: \(String(describing: response.result.value))")   // result of response serialization
        print("Error: \(String(describing: response.error))")

        var json = JSON(response.result.value)
        print(json)
//            
//            let fname: String = json[]["fname"].stringValue
//            print(fname)


//            
//            for (index, object) in json {
//                let fname = object["fname"].stringValue
//                print(fname)
//            }




//            if let data = response.result.value?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8){
//                do {
//                    employeeDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
//                    
//                    if let myDictionary = employeeDict{
//                        print("First name is: \(myDictionary["fname"]!)")
//                    }
//                }
//            }

//            guard let object = response.result.value else{
//                print("Error")
//                return
//            }
//
//            let json = JSON(object)
//            if let jsonArray = json.array{
//                if let user_id = jsonArray[0]["user_id"].array{
//                    if let fname = jsonArray[1]["fname"].array{
//                         print(user_id)
//                    }
//                }
//            }
    }
```

I can print the JSON data out, but cannot access any of the information or store any of it in a dictionary.

Comment: Look at the JSON structure. It's an array containing an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SwiftyJSON, because I am fine using JSONSerialization, so I don't know what data type your json variable is, also I take it that response.result.value is of type Data.

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.result.value, options: .mutableContainers) else { return }

guard let rootArray = json as? Array<Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>> else { return }

let array = rootArray[0] // The outer/root array seems useless from what you have shown in your JSON above, so this is to get to the array of dictionaries.

for item in array {

    print(item["job_title"]) // prints out "Optional(job_title)"
}
```